# How to override the "public" directory?

Tags: symfony, symfony4, webpack-encore, symfony5

I've renamed my `public` directory into `www` so as the documentation says I've added some line in `composer.json` file:

```
"extra": {
    "...": "...",
    "public-dir": "www"
}
```

Then I ran `composer update`.

But it seems not to work.

I have this error :

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Asset manifest file "*******/public/build/manifest.json" does not exist.").

So I've added in `config/packages/dev/framework.yaml` (I'm on dev):

```
framework:
    assets:
        json_manifest_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/www/build/manifest.json'
```

But another error has appeared:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Could not find the entrypoints file from Webpack: the file "*******/public/build/entrypoints.json" does not exist.").

Then I modify webpack.config.js file like this :

```
Encore
    // directory where compiled assets will be stored
    .setOutputPath('www/build/')
```

But the error is still there.

Is there a simple way to rename the public directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've fixed my issue :

In config/packages/webpack_encore.yaml :

```
webpack_encore:
    # The path where Encore is building the assets.
    # This should match Encore.setOutputPath() in webpack.config.js.
    output_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/www/build'
```